# Why this php code does not execute the SqL Server query completely?

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am having trouble with this php code, the problem is that I have tried to insert 1000 rows on a Sql Server table but the code just inserts 80 rows and I do not know why, I have executed the Sql Server procedure alone on the Sql Server Management Studio and works good but when I try to execute from php It does not work, I also set the "remote query time out" to "no timeout". Here is the code that I am using. Help please.

PHP CODE

```
<?php 

$myServer = "servername"; 
$conex=array("Database"=>"database");   
$conn = sqlsrv_connect ($myServer, $conex) ;

 if ( sqlsrv_begin_transaction( $conn ) === false ) {
 die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true ));
}

$sql="insertarDistrito_Sql ?";
$params=array(&$_POST(1000));

$stmt=sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql, $params);  


if( $stmt) {
 sqlsrv_commit( $conn );
 echo "Transaction committed.<br />";
} else {
 sqlsrv_rollback( $conn );
 echo "Transaction rolled back.<br />";
}
?>
```

SQL SERVER STORED PROCEDURE

```
CREATE procedure [dbo].[insertarDistrito_Sql]
@cant int
As
Declare @i int 
Declare @w int
Declare @id int
SET @i = 1
set @w=1
set @id=1

if (Select count(*) from distrito)> 0
begin
    Set @id= (select max([id_distrito]) from  [dbo].[distrito]) 
    set @id=@id+1
end
WHILE(@i <= @cant)
BEGIN       

INSERT INTO [dbo].[distrito] ([id_distrito], [id_warehouse], [d_nombre],      [d_direccion], [d_calle1], 
                        [d_calle2],[d_barrio], [d_fecha_creacion],[d_capacidad])
                            VALUES(@id,@w,newid(),newid(),newid(),newid(),newid(), '12/12/2014',rand())
SET @i += 1         
set @id +=1     
END
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be PHP that is timing out, try putting

```
 set_time_limit(0);
```

at the top of your PHP file.